# To reverse the values from up to down and change y-axis too in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Example data:

[image]

I can change the values from up to down by the command

```
B(end:-1:1,:)
```

I run it and get

[image]

However, I want to change the values on the y-axis such that they go from 0 to 180.

**How can you change the values on the y-axis in Matlab?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change direction of y axis, including axis labels and plotted values, you use

```
set(gca,'YDir','reverse')
```

When you plot an image, for example using `imagesc`, the `YDir` property is automatically set to `reverse`. So, to change it, set it to `normal`:

```
set(gca,'YDir','normal')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! In my case, the problem was solved by using the word *normal* in *set(gca,'YDir','normal')* and removing the part *(end:-1:1,:)* from *B*.

Comment: @Masi You're right. When you plot an image, the `YDir` property is set to `reverse`. So to reverse that you need `normal`. I'm updating the answer to include that